# Optimizing my loop python for speed

Tags: loops, python-3.5

My function is trying to get a range of yearmonth strings in a list from two dates.

I've been working at it for awhile and managed to code a very poor solution. I would like some help how to optimize my algorithm.

my initial impression was to evaluate the algorithm with

```
while (beginMonth!=endMonth) and (beginYear!=endYear)
```

but this evaluated to false for the input values of

beginYear = 2016 and beginMonth = 10

endYear = 2017 and endMonth = 02

returning

["201610", "201611", "201612"]

it exited the loop earlier than i expected.

So given the input 
fromDate = "201610"
toDate = "201702"

it should return
["201610", "201611", "201612", "201701", "201702"]

particularly i have concerns about this loop

**Loop of inefficiency**

```
while True:
    dateRange.append(str(beginYear) + str(beginMonth).zfill(2))
    if beginYear >= endYear:
        if beginMonth >= endMonth:
            break
    beginMonth = beginMonth + 1
    if (beginMonth > 12):
        beginMonth = 1
        beginYear = beginYear + 1
    print("inc {0}{1}".format(beginYear,str(beginMonth).zfill(2)))
```

**Full code**

```
def getRange(fromDate, toDate):
    dateRange = []
    beginYear = int(fromDate[:4])
    beginMonth = int(fromDate[-2:])
    endYear = int(toDate[:4])
    endMonth = int(toDate[-2:])

    if endYear < beginYear:
        print("End year must be less than begin year")
        return
    elif endYear - beginYear > 25:
        print("Maximum number of years reached, can't analyse more than 25 
years")

    else:
        #iterate from current date one month at a time to end date
        while True:
            dateRange.append(str(beginYear) + str(beginMonth).zfill(2))
            if beginYear >= endYear:
                if beginMonth >= endMonth:
                    break
            beginMonth = beginMonth + 1
            if (beginMonth > 12):
                beginMonth = 1
                beginYear = beginYear + 1
            print("inc {0}{1}".format(beginYear,str(beginMonth).zfill(2)))
    return dateRange
```

Comment: The loop itself is okay,some choices you've done in it are the problem. I'll make an answer when I get home, I'm expecting a 40% boost,at least. Anyway,if speed is a big problem,try using PyPy too.

Comment: If you just dislike the while and the two nested if-s, you can achieve something similar using ```while (beginYear < endYear) or (beginMonth <= endMonth)``` instead.